# iOS, Problems in the UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, pushviewcontroller

My bug is as follows:

In ViewList I have the code below which does push the ViewManager;

```
- (Void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
     PropertyManagerViewController propertyManagerViewController * = [[PropertyManagerViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @ "PropertyManagerViewController" bundle: nil];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController: propertyManagerViewController animated: YES];

}
```

In ViewManager create the UITabBarController :

```
- (void) createTabBarController
{
       [ ShowTabBarController showTabBar : self.navigationController.tabBarController ] ;

        NSMutableArray * viewControllers = [ [ NSMutableArray alloc ] init ] ;
         UITabBarController * TabBarController = [ [ UITabBarController alloc ] init ] ;

        ViewController * viewController = [ [ ViewController alloc ] initWithNibName : @ " ViewController " bundle: nil ] ;
         UINavigationController * navigationController = [ [ UINavigationController alloc ] initWithRootViewController : ViewController ] ;
         [ ViewControllers addObject : navigationController ] ;

        ViewController2 viewController2 * = [ [ VisitDetailsViewController alloc ] initWithNibName : @ " ViewController2 " bundle: nil ] ;
         UINavigationController * navigationController2 = [ [ UINavigationController alloc ] initWithRootViewController : ViewController2 ] ;
         [ ViewControllers addObject : navigationController2 ] ;

         tabBarController.viewControllers = viewControllers ;
         self.navigationController.tabBarController.viewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers ;

} .
```

In ViewController and View ViewController2 have this method to push the ViewList.

```
-(void)pushTableList
{
    [ShowTabBarController hideTabBar:self.tabBarController];

    PropertyListViewController *propertyList = [[PropertyListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PropertyListViewController" bundle:nil];
```

[UIView  beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

```
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:propertyList animated:NO];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

My problem now is:

- When I'm in ViewController2 pushTableList and I 'm going to viewlist .
- Then select another line , doing push ViewManager and the view that shows me is the last which was , in this case ViewController2 .

Update :

I want to click the table cell and then push the ViewController. The problem is: I click on the cell, the view is showing ViewContoller 2 (which is the last view I had) when I push to ViewList.

New Update

1 - Push and create UITabBArController

```
-(Void) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    PropertyManagerViewController propertyManagerViewController * = [[PropertyManagerViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @ "PropertyManagerViewController" bundle: nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: propertyManagerViewController animated: YES];

}
- (void) createTabBarController
{
    [ ShowTabBarController showTabBar : self.navigationController.tabBarController ] ;

    NSMutableArray * viewControllers = [ [ NSMutableArray alloc ] init ] ;
    UITabBarController * TabBarController = [ [ UITabBarController alloc ] init ] ;

    ViewController * viewController = [ [ ViewController alloc ] initWithNibName : @ " ViewController " bundle: nil ] ;
    UINavigationController * navigationController = [ [ UINavigationController alloc ] initWithRootViewController : ViewController ] ;
    [ ViewControllers addObject : navigationController ] ;

    ViewController2 viewController2 * = [ [ VisitDetailsViewController alloc ] initWithNibName : @ " ViewController2 " bundle: nil ] ;
    UINavigationController * navigationController2 = [ [ UINavigationController alloc ] initWithRootViewController : ViewController2 ] ;
    [ ViewControllers addObject : navigationController2 ] ;
    ViewController3 viewController3 * = [ [ VisitDetailsViewController alloc ] initWithNibName : @ " ViewController3 " bundle: nil ] ;
    UINavigationController * navigationController3 = [ [ UINavigationController alloc ] initWithRootViewController : ViewController2 ] ;
    [ ViewControllers addObject : navigationController3 ] ;

    tabBarController.viewControllers = viewControllers ;
    self.navigationController.tabBarController.viewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers ;

}
```

[image]

2 - Select TabBarITem Visit Details and click UIBarButtonItem Property List

[image]

3 - Click on the Cell of the da table.

[image]

4 -  Here's the my problem. If you look back to tabbaritem Visit. I want you to show me PropertyItem
[image]

Comment: "What should happen and wanted to show me was that if the ViewController and not the last view" ???

Comment: I'd really like to help, but I don't understand the question. Could you add these points to your question:

 1. What are you trying to do?
 2. How are you trying to do it?
 3. What is the unintended result?

Comment: @JohannesFahrenkrug new post!

Comment: Your view hierarchy is really messed up. I'm happy to try to help, but you need to story board your ideas and learn some of the basics about [View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457).

Answer (score 1):

you might want to check out this document: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html

One very important piece of information: a UITabBarController always has to be the top-level controller! You are not allowed to put a UITabBarController inside of a UINavigationController. You are allowed, however, to put a UINavigationController inside of a UITabBarController. The [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/pushViewController%3aanimated%3a) about UINavigationController's pushViewController:animated: method say:

> The view controller that is pushed onto the stack. This object cannot
>   be an instance of tab bar controller and it must not already be on the
>   navigation stack.

I hope this points you into the right direction.